# SQL query optimization: get extra column data from non-clustered index

Tags: sql, query-optimization, non-clustered-index

I am trying to write a query on a table that receives millions of records per day. I can narrow my query down to a time slice (`logdate`), but I need additional column data from it (`num`). Here is a sample query I'm using to test it:

```
DECLARE @StartTimeStamp DATETIME = '12/6/2019 7:56:50.799'
DECLARE @EndTimeStamp DATETIME = '12/6/2019 7:56:50.8'

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT tx.num, tx.logdate 
FROM hsi.transactionxlog tx
WHERE tx.logdate BETWEEN @StartTimeStamp AND @EndTimeStamp
```

This particular test, with a time span of .001 seconds, takes over four minutes to run. If I change it to a timeframe with no records found in the specified timeframe, then it takes almost perhaps one second to run, even specifying a span of 24 hours.

This table only has non-clustered indexes. One such index has the following columns in it: (`num`, `logdate`, and `action`, in that order).

How can I find the `num` corresponding to each record between @StartTimeStamp and @EndTimeStamp quickly? I would strongly prefer not to create additional indexes on this table, since many other application use it so often.

Comment: It's a pretty straigth query which can speedup if you add the lodate in the index.Are you going to query on the milliseconds or date wise? Reason I am asking is if its  date wise you might consider using = Date_field instead of between. Also have you checked what does the explain plan and tuning advisor say?

Comment: The table has two indexes on it that have logdate, one is `logdate`, `action`, and `usernum` and the other as posted above. I do intend to usually query for about five minutes at a time, so sorry but I can't use =. I isolated it to the smallest time range possible to try to find out what the maximum time range was I could use. I don't know anything about an explain plan or tuning advisor, but will look into these, if I have rights on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temp table solution. Here is the essence of the solution:

```
DECLARE @StartTimeStamp DATETIME = '12/6/2019 7:56:50.799'
DECLARE @EndTimeStamp DATETIME = '12/6/2019 7:56:50.8'
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (logdate DATETIME, action BIGINT)

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT logdate, action FROM hsi.transactionxlog
    WHERE logdate BETWEEN @StartTimeStamp AND @EndTimeStamp

SELECT tx.num, tx.logdate 
FROM hsi.transactionxlog tx
INNER JOIN @TempTable t ON t.logdate = tx.logdate AND t.action = tx.action
WHERE tx.logdate BETWEEN @StartTimeStamp AND @EndTimeStamp
```

I don't really have a good explanation for why this works, but it is much faster, and time scales properly with the time difference between `@StartTimeStamp` and `@EndTimeStamp`. It simply selects the few thousand records, then for some reason it's easier for SQL to find them in the large table.

Thank you for looking at the question and trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select tx.num, tx.logdate
from hsi.transactionxlog tx
where tx.logdate BETWEEN @StartTimeStamp AND @EndTimeStamp;
```

The optimal index is:  `transactionxlog(logdate, num)`.  The `logdate` should be the first key in the index so it is used for the `where` condition.

Comment: If I can avoid it, I would like to not add indexes to this table, because it is such an integral part of other applications. Abandoning my own application might even be a better option.